Port Forwarding inability on COX internet
I have tried all normal methods of port forwarding to no avail.
WAN IP shown in orbilogin.com is the same as shown in whatismyip.com for this reason I am assuming that I have a IPV4 public to WAN and have not been provided a NAT by COX.
COX residential Wi-Fi does not automatically disable port forwarding > confirmed by technician this morning
The Router is mine and the Modem is property of COX
The complete flow is: HFC>Modem>Router>Laptop
The first 5 digits of public IP: 98.180
Setup:
Orbi RBR850 for router
ARRIS CM8200A for modem
The responses from COX have been far from helpful:
https://forums.cox.com/discussions/internet/cgnat-or-not-why-cant-i-port-forward/155024
and have been directly conflicting with technicians I have talked with face to face (that modem is not the issue)
Word for word from technician:
"High ports should be open on HFC. The only restricted ones are inbound port 25, 80, and 443 for mail and web servers."
See attached document for my full processes. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7qNNC_wWd27V0ggBMK9ANSBIxZk9gOT
Yes I have seen threads such as:
Port forwarding failing every single time despite correct settings in router (moved from stackoverflow)
Router port forwarding is unsuccessful (can add them, but they don't seem to open)

If you put the ARRIS modem in bridge mode you should be able to forward ports, as to my knowledge, COX does not utilize CGNAT in any of their service areas. COX forums are full of, to be frank, of self help users who know nothing about the topic they reply to. I know this should be possible as I had a COX supplied COX Arris modem for years before I decided to purchase my own ARRIS modem and both supported bridge mode

I think my main issue is that I am in a "community wifi" and the modem does not show up whatsoever in the "My equipment" tab of their website... The only modem I have access to is not on their list of approved modems (ref: https://www.cox.com/residential/support/cox-certified-cable-modems.html ) so I am doubtful it is worth the 2 hour drive each way to get it. At this point it may be the only solution as I have no control over the current modem

Just spent 45 mins with COX support trying to ask them to add the modem they provided to my account so I can attempt to set it to bridge mode, they could not do it and left it at that. Cool.

Did you try the self-service option?

"Community wifi"? Is this a shared wifi covering an area such as an apartment complex, or a connection through a device you own or lease? Also, please avoid saying "I tried all/everything..." like you do in your opener. List each and every specific thing you have tried with enough detail that we will recognize precisely what you've done.

Check the link I provided in my post for an organized step by step of each process I did with screenshots of each step and complete prints of standard debugging commands.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H7qNNC_wWd27V0ggBMK9ANSBIxZk9gOT
As for the "community wifi", it was routed through their switch and paid for by the apartment complex as part of the monthly rent, but other than that it is bog standard HFC from best I can tell, I tested both with and without their switch in line to 0  difference between the two, so I have permanently unplugged their switch.

Their original layout was as follows:
HFC>Modem>switch>Ethernet to POE adapter> POE router
Which I changed to
HFC>Modem>My Router
And yes the port forwarding was identical with these two setups (completely non operational)
